# Property 'element' does not exist on type 'Element' ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript

I can not find a solution to my error.
in the ng serve it works very well, once I go to do the ng build --prod there is an error that bugs me:
Property 'element' does not exist on type 'Element'.

[image]

Edit-depart.html

```
  <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)" novalidate>
      <input  type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]="data.element.id" />
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>Modifier Courrier Depart</h2>
    <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header fxLayoutAlign="center">                
          <mat-card-subtitle><h2>Information</h2></mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <table cellspacing="2" class="w-100">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline" >
                  <mat-select placeholder="Type Contrat" name="type" [(ngModel)]="data.element.type">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let contrat of contrats" [value]="contrat.value" >
                       {{contrat.viewValue}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
                <input matInput placeholder="Destinataire" name="destinataire" [(ngModel)]="data.element.destinataire">
             
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid" [mat-dialog-close]>Update</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
    </form>
```

departs.component.ts

```
editDepart(element: Element) {
   // this.selectedEmployee = element;
   
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDepart,  { disableClose: true,data: { element } }); 
    
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.refreshEmployeeList();
    })    
    
   }
```

```
export interface Element {
  id: any;
  type: any;
  destinataire: any;
}
```

Edit-depart

```
  export class EditDepart {

     constructor( private _employeeService: EmployeeService,
```

public dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Element) {

```
     }
    
    @Output() submit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    
     onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
      if (form.value.id == null) {
        this._employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
          
          this._employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((res) => {
           
              this.submit.next(res as Employee[]);
           
          });
        //  M.toast({ html: "Saved successfully.", classes: "rounded" });
        });
      }
      else {
    
        this._employeeService.putEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
          
          this._employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((res) => {
              this.submit.next(res as Employee[]);
              //this.employees = employees;
           
          });
          
        });
      }
    }
      
     
    }
```

Comment: it seems that it is assuming data to have the type as Element. Try to set a type for data attribute, also, if possible, can you paste your edit-department.ts file, which can help in understanding the problem better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In edit depart component you have declared

```
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Element) {
```

This is expecting data to be of type Element when actually data has type {element: Element}

You can change it to

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
```

or change the value assigned to data like

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDepart,  { disableClose: true,data: { ...element } });
```